# How to update hg with ignoring one file

Tags: mercurial

When checking **hg verify**

```
portfolio/600x600/72.jpg@8: unpacking 346174023f35: revlog decompress error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect data check
```

And I need update another files except this. Have any command in **hg** for do this?

for example from version 49 to 50 
**like this**

```
hg update 50 -ignore portfolio/600x600/72.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating to a revision does not support this. However you can **revert** selected files to a certain revision:

```
hg revert -rXXX FILENAME
```

it also supports the `--exclude` and `--include` flags, so you could try:

```
hg revert -r50 --all --exclude portfolio/600x600/72.jpg
```

Mind: the repository will be a modified state after this, should you commit, the parent will be your currently checked-out revision.